# How do I get Shiny App to display results on when condition is met, and clear otherwise?

Tags: r, shiny

I'm using a Shiny App to run a lottery. I have the user set the seed, and set it twice to confirm. I'd like for the results to appear only while the seeds are identical. This code works to not show results until seeds are identical, but I'd like for the results to disappear if the user later changes the seeds to anything not identical. How can I get that? I tried observe({}) but couldn't get it to work.

Here's an example:

```
library(dplyr)
library(shiny)

women <- data.frame( id = c(1, 2, 3, 4), firstname = c("Joan", "Robin",  "Anne", "Mary"), lastname = c("Jett", "Reynolds", "Adams", "Martin")) 

shinyApp(

ui<-fluidPage(

    fluidRow(
    column(6, numericInput("num", label = h1("Enter the seed"), value = NA)),
    column(6, numericInput("num2", label = h1("Confirm the seed"), value = NA))
    ),
    fluidRow(verbatimTextOutput("value")),
    fluidRow("These are the women selected in the lottery:", tableOutput("women")),
    ), #CLOSE FLUIDPAGE
server<- function(input, output) {
    output$value <- renderPrint({
    set.seed(input$num) #SET THE SEED
    women_winners<-sample_n(women, 3, replace = FALSE)
    w_output<-subset(women_winners, select=c("firstname", "lastname"))
    #Send the winners' names to be output
    if (input$num==input$num2){ #PUT ALL INSIDE THIS SO IT WON'T RUN UNTIL MET
    output$women <- renderTable(w_output)
    }
    }) 
}, #CLOSE SERVER
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the code below gives you what you want.  Compared to your version, I've separated the construction of the output object from its display.  That's generally good practice.

Also, you nest the creation of an output widget `output$women` inside a `renderXXX` call.  I've never found a situation in which that is a good thing to do, though in some simple situations it doesn't cause immediate problems.

I've also added a call to `req()` to remove the warning message that is printed to the console without it.

```
library(dplyr)
library(shiny)

women <- data.frame( id = c(1, 2, 3, 4), firstname = c("Joan", "Robin",  "Anne", "Mary"), lastname = c("Jett", "Reynolds", "Adams", "Martin")) 

shinyApp(
  ui<-fluidPage(
    fluidRow(
      column(6, numericInput("num", label = h1("Enter the seed"), value = NA)),
      column(6, numericInput("num2", label = h1("Confirm the seed"), value = NA))
    ),
    fluidRow(verbatimTextOutput("value")),
    fluidRow("These are the women selected in the lottery:", tableOutput("women")),
  ), 
  server<- function(input, output) {
    winners <- reactive({
      req(input$num, input$num2)
      
      if (input$num == input$num2) {
        sample_n(women, 3, replace = FALSE)
      }
    })
    
    output$value <- renderPrint({
      winners()
    }) 
  }
)
```